# MongoDB aggregate Query with select fields

Tags: mongodb

I want to make chat system, and also need get last message of user which aggigation. I also provide query with this but it only return userId of user. so please help me, thanks

Database:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56937df0418a6afab248616d"),
    "to" : ObjectId("56728051d4b426be03de18f2"),
    "from" : ObjectId("568e402eaecfa53282f60d17"),
    "msg" : "Hello!",
    "cd" : ISODate("2016-01-11T10:03:28.139Z"),
    "type" : "other",
    "ir" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56937e01418a6afab248616e"),
    "to" : ObjectId("568e402eaecfa53282f60d17"),
    "from" : ObjectId("56728051d4b426be03de18f2"),
    "msg" : "Hi!",
    "cd" : ISODate("2016-01-11T10:03:45.588Z"),
    "type" : "other",
    "ir" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56937e45418a6afab248616f"),
    "to" : ObjectId("56728051d4b426be03de18f2"),
    "from" : ObjectId("568e402eaecfa53282f60d17"),
    "msg" : "Shu che ela!",
    "cd" : ISODate("2016-01-11T10:04:53.280Z"),
    "type" : "other",
    "ir" : 0
}
```

Query:

```
db.getCollection('chat_message').aggregate( [
        { 
            $match: {
                ir: 0, 
                $or : [
                    {"to" : ObjectId("56728051d4b426be03de18f2")}
                ]  
            } 
        },

        { $group: { _id: "$from" } },

    ])
```

I Run this query but not get result which i want

Require Out came:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("568e402eaecfa53282f60d17"),
            "msg" : "Shu che ela!"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right track but you missing some things about **[$mongo object Id](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)**

> > In MongoDB, documents stored in a collection require a unique _id field that acts as a primary key.

so when you run your aggregation query `$group` creates `_id` for `from` key but in your document structure looks like `from` having two documents with same `ObjectId` since the result return first matching criteria. This return only `"msg" : "Hello!",` or `"msg" : "Shu che ela!"` which documents inserted first return first.

so should changed your aggreation like this `{"$group":{"_id":"$_id","msg":{"$first":"$msg"}}}` you will get both documents.

Comment: db.getCollection('chat_message').aggregate( [
        { 
            $match: {
                ir: 0, 
                $or : [
                    {"to" : ObjectId("56728051d4b426be03de18f2")}
                ]  
            } 
        },

        {"$group":{"_id":"$from","msg":{"$last":"$msg"}}}

    ])

I put this query and i got last message as par i want.
thanks.